# How to find the substring over many iterations on the same string

Tags: python

I have a simple string `thetext = "Dairy-Milk    Price:800     Qty: 1"`.

What I want is to get the value after the last colon `:`.
I'm able to do that with this: `thetext[thetext.rfind(':') + 1:]`

However I'm doing this repeatedly and it only lasts up to the 3rd iteration then throws `invalid literal for int() value error`, how can I achieve the same for limitless iterations?

What am doing is taking `thetext` and changing the last quantity by updating the number and calling the method on `thetext` again, now this is repeated several times and the above solution lasts for only 3 iterations, is there any solution for this?

**EDIT**

I apologize my previous explanation might have been misleading or unclear,

```
        #Here self.dynamic_ids[] simply gets the text from kivi UI
        thetext = self.dynamic_ids[current_Item_Name].text

        #A sample text looks like the one above
        sample_text = "Dairy-Milk    Price:800     Qty: 1"

        #Lets set it to thetext
        thetext = sample_text

        #Now I try to find the colon and get the input at the end, 1 as Eg
        result =  thetext[thetext.rfind(':') + 1:]

        #I add 1 to that number and store it in the variable the new number
        thenewnumber = int(result) + 1
        
        #Return the new text to the UI by splitting and adding 
        self.dynamic_ids[current_Item_Name].text = thetext.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]+ str(thenewnumber)
```

I realize the problem might be while splitting before joining at the end to create a new string, please give me some insights.

Comment: Can you share the exact code that is causing the error? It's unclear from your description exactly what you are doing

Comment: Have you consider using regular expressions to find the matches?

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is :

- Get the value located after the last colon (and we assume that these last characters of the string (the "value") will be a number, composed of one or more digits)
- Replace this "value"
- And do this multiple times

You could do this :

```
thetext = "Dairy-Milk Price:800 Qty: 1"

# Split on colon
thetext_splitted = thetext.split(":")

# Get last value (strip() removes spaces)
last_value = thetext_splitted[-1].strip()

# New value in order to update "thetext" (as string, not as int)
new_last_value = "200"

# Create the new list, updated with the new value
thetext_splitted[-1] = new_last_value

# Recreate "thetext"
new_thetext = ":".join(thetext_splitted)

print(new_thetext)
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the string is s = "Dairy-Milk Price:800 Qty: 1".

You can retrieve this value at the end with:

```
val = s.split(":")[-1]
```

Keep in mind that it will be still a string and not an integer value.

If your strings are stacked in a list **L**, you can loop over all elements of the list:

```
for element in L:
    val = element.split(":")[-1]
```

In that case you have to store them somewhere.

Comment: i believe hi is trying to do that over many iterations, so this isn't many helpful